# VHDL: How to specify inner dimension of std_logic_vector array in port using generic?

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog

In VHDL we can constrain the length of an std_logic_vector in port map as follows:

```
entity fdct_coeff_rom is
  generic (
    data_len : integer range 1 to 8
  );
  port (
    i_clk    : in std_logic;
    i_rst_n  : in std_logic;
    i_data   : in std_logic_vector(data_len-1 downto 0);
    i_we     : in std_logic;
    i_re     : in std_logic;
    o_data   : out std_logic_vector(data_len-1 downto 0)
  );
```

I have an array of std_logic_vectors in the port map. The ports are 8 std_logic_vectors, the length of which can change. Now I am not sure how to use generic to change the length of each std_logic_vector. Is this possible?

```
entity fdct_coeff_rom is
  generic (
    data_len : integer range 1 to 8
  );
  port (
    i_clk    : in std_logic;
    i_rst_n  : in std_logic;
    i_data   : in data_arr_t; -- 8 std_logic_vector, each data_len-1 downto 0
    i_we     : in std_logic;
    i_re     : in std_logic;
    o_data   : out data_arr_t  -- 8 std_logic_vector, each data_len-1 downto 0
  );
```

The data_arry_t is defined in a package as an array of std_logic_vector. I am not sure how I can specify the size of the std_logic_vector using a generic such that, each instance of the module has a different length of the std_logic_vector.

Please note that the module I am dealing with is complex, the example in this question is just to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Now, if this is not at all possible in VHDL, can this be done in SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 1):

VHDL 2008 allows all dimensions to be unconstrained when a type is defined. So, first create a package with the type:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package my_pkg is
  type slv_array_t is array(natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;
end package;
```

Now define the entity:

```
-- use VHDL-2008

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

library work;
use work.my_pkg.all;

entity my_entity is
  generic(
    N : natural := 8;
    WW : natural := 16
  );
  port (
    i_clk   : in std_logic;
    i_data  : in slv_array_t(0 to N-1)(WW-1 downto 0);
    o_data  : out slv_array_t(0 to N-1)(WW-1 downto 0)
  );
end entity;

architecture rtl of my_entity is

begin

  process(i_clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(i_clk) then
      o_data <= i_data;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

Take note of how the 2D array is being constrained in both dimensions, inner and outer.

```
i_data  : in slv_array_t(0 to N-1)(WW-1 downto 0);
o_data  : out slv_array_t(0 to N-1)(WW-1 downto 0)
```

This must be compiled with VHDL-2008 enabled. This will synthesize in Intel Quartus Prime, Xilinx Vivado and also Microsemi Libero SoC as long as the VHDL-2008 setting is specifie.

Comment: In my_pkg composite array type slv_array_t has a single index, it's not a multidimensional array type while it's element type happens to be a composite array type with a single index. An object of type slv_array_t is not a 2D array. An indexed name specifies a specific element, a slice name a range of elements. A multidimensional (2D) array type can't be sliced. You can have an indexed name whose prefix is an indexed name and designates an element of a std_logic_vector and is a subelement of a slv_array_t.  See Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types and 8. Names.

Comment: I do not understand what you said, is there an example of what you are referring to?